# PHP MySQL - time is approximately 1 minute and 30 seconds advanced in server

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new in MySQL and PHP programming and I've developed a web app wherein I have an "Activity Log" section where timestamps are needed. I recently found out that the date/time of servers are different from the local server used during development. My solution was to replace the "Now()" MySQL function with the code below:

```
//Setting default datetime
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Singapore");
$dt = strval(date("Y-m-d / h:i:sa"));

//Inserting datetime into database
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO logs (admin, description, dt) VALUES ('$admin','$dsc','$dt');";
```

This worked for me but the timestamps are now ahead by roughly 1min and 30sec in the online server. It may be a slight difference but I would like to know if 100% accuracy is possible. Also, please excuse me for not using prepared statements. I'll be getting to that soon.

Comment: usually a timeserver is called to get the precise time, you should increase the cron job that does it on your server.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements with placeholder values** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Tip: Instead of defining SQL in a throw-away variable like `$sql6` that could easily be mistaken for another, supply the query string *directly* to the database function in question. Finding a bug caused by accidentally running the wrong query is not fun.

Comment: what kind of server are you running this on? I believe you just need to sync the time there. If it's a linux it would be something like `ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` and then add it to crontab to be run a few times a day, then you will get the accuracy.

Comment: I'm using free web hosting (InfinityFree) since this is only for our school project. I've done more observation and noticed that the timestamps are 10 seconds to 2 minutes advanced.